# About Frobenius Determinant Theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, polynomials, finite-groups

Finite group $G=\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}$. Consider $G$'s multiplication table to be an $n\times n$ matrix $A$. Set $x_i=1$, $x_j=0$ ($j≠i$), $1≤i≤n$, then we get $n$ permutation matrices $S_i$ ($1≤i≤n$) s.t. $A=∑x_iS_i$. DetA is called groupdet, which is a polynomial of n variables. DetA is reducible with at least a factor ∑xi. So we're able to find a common invariant subspace of $S_i$ (considering them to be linear transformation on $V$). If we can find another common invariant subspace $V_1$ ($V=V_1⊕W$), there must exist a linear transformation $T$ s.t. $T(V_1)=V_1$, $T(W)=V_1$. Let $T'=∑S_iTS_i^{-1}$. Then $V=T'(V_1) \oplus \ker T'$ and $\ker T'$ is a common invariant subspace. Thus there exists matrix $H$ s.t. $HAH^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(A_1,A_2,....A_m)$ and it's unable to find smaller blocks in $A_k$.

I find it difficult to prove detAk are irreducible without group representation. Let Ak=∑xiHSiH^(-1)=(aij) If aij are linearly independent over C, add some other characters bj(1≤j≤n-k^2) s.t. ring C[x1,x2,... xn]≌C[a11, a12,... akk, b1,...], then aij are algebraically independent over C. If detAk=fg and f contains a11, a1i and ai1 mustn't be contained in g. Similarly, all aij are not contained in g, so g is constant. Thus detAk is irreducible.

My question: how to prove aij are linearly independent? I think we just need to prove that aij≠0 for all i and j. I know Frobenius established the theories with concepts like group character, but I still hope that the proof does not use group character and group representation theory or use only a little of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A very nice introduction to the whole theory (including indications of and references to the non-representation-theoretic approach) are given, in a typically lucid manner, by [Keith Conrad.](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/articles/groupdet.pdf)